# what is different in [-1] ,[:1]?

Tags: for-loop, cjk

i know [-1]

but i don't understand [:-1] mean,,

ex)~~{}txt -> Number of births file

ls=()
for y in range(1990,2000):
filname = "~~{}.txt".format(y)
with open ("filename",'r') as f:
data=filename.realines()
for d in data():
if d[-1]:
d=d[-1]
birth=data.split(",")[2]
cnt += birth
ls.append(y,cnt)

with open("birth_year.csv","w") as f:
for year,birth in ls:
data ="{},{}\n".format(year,birth)
f.write

what mean [:-1]???...

I am not good at  coding.
so,I'd appreciate it if you'd be kind enough to tell me know. thx

Comment: Could you please edit the question to format your code? There are some formatting tools in the bar at the top of the text field. This would highly increase readability and make the question easier to understand and answer.

Comment: Also, you should tag the programming langage you are using.

Comment: This said, I guess what you are looking at is [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)